# Resources for learning Portuguese

Tags: recursos, recursos-online

Following the [Russian Resources question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian), the aim of this post is to gather and list resources for learning Portuguese.

I think it is desirable to distinguish between European and Brazilian Portuguese. It is not, by any means, some sort of segregation. However, since different people have different goals, the distinction makes sense.

**European Portuguese**

- [RTP - Rádio e Televisão de Portugual](https://www.rtp.pt/play/direto), online streaming from state owned portuguese TV.
- [Expresso](http://expresso.sapo.pt/), portuguese newspaper.

**Brazilian Portuguese**

- [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/), free internet course (web-based and mobile app).
- [Clozemaster](https://www.clozemaster.com/), free internet course (web-based).

Note: I am writing in English so that this becomes visible to a wider public. I ask for the help of moderators to further expand, and to guide the expansion.

Comment: I suggest that the question is made Community Wiki, and that the explanations and external links to its russian equivalent become a note at the bottom of the question and not a main part of the question.

Comment: Also, in my opinion this question is on-topic, according to a discussion on meta about reference questions: https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/should-we-allow-reference-questions-on-main

Comment: Today a great resource to learn ant language is the internet, in this case  I can point youtube. Lot's of popular shows/movies you like can be found in another language. For example if you are used to watch The Simpson in germany you can watch again the same episodes on portuguese. The familiarity with the show will help you to get context and catch the language

Comment: @jean You should elaborate your commentary as an answer, as the method you described is, indeed, a very useful one.

Comment: @William see my answer below

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question about Portuguese. It's about learning Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

This information is about **European Portuguese** which is what I am learning, though most can be extrapolated to Brazilian Portuguese, for sure.

About **Android apps**, which I have used and can recommend:

I have used [**MemRise**](https://app.memrise.com/es/courses/english/portuguese-portugal-2/) a lot, free or paying app, which has 7 levels of European Portuguese and also community created courses.

Also [**AnkiDroid**](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) which is a card-based app (words and phrases, with sound recordings in some of them) though it is a bit harder for setting up so I don't recommend it unless you want to spend a bit of time searching for courses and installing them manually. There are [a lot of decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/portuguese) for practice.

**Podcasts**:

Apart from that, there are some very helpful podcasts at Spotify, like "[**Portugueses no Mundo**](https://open.spotify.com/show/36OAbErwr710Rm6UGvH5R3)" or "[**Portugueses com História**](https://open.spotify.com/show/4VBj1PAj6K59RmqjEsvzjn)" which are RTP radio programs.

There is also "**[Practice Portuguese](https://www.practiceportuguese.com/)**". They now have an app, are present on most social networks, [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/PracticePortuguese) etc.
Most of the content is for members only (monthly fee) but they also have free resources (as many YouTube videos) and they have very good quality.

Answer (score -2):

I have never studied english formally and all my knowledge comes from self study. Most of my writing and reading skills I have developed by struggling with a dictionary and english texts from books, magazines, comics and games - I feel reading comics and books I already have read in portuguese helped me to get context, and context is necessary to get a understanding of the text.

It's specially helpful to weigh intensity and feelings from some words/expressions. Old 8-bits Games like Civilization (and its "civilopedia") have lots of text and are also a good starting point, because they create an immediate curiosity for the game mechanics and history ("need to"). This feeling of "I need this knowledge to make my decisions and win" helps a lot to fuel your progress, and in fact you forget you started it to practice your english, and read it in a more natural way.

Later I started to get some speaking and listening skills by watching movies. Again I started by watching shows and movies I had already watched in Portuguese.

This familiarity helped me a lot to understand things because the main difference between learning to read/write and listen/speak is that when you are reading you get time to stop and search in a dictionary (note: when you get enough vocabulary - I started to use a english dictionary like Webster). While watching a movie it is easy to miss a word and get the context wrong. Also, even if you cannot tell whether the actor spoke "beer" or "bear" just by the sound of it you can easily catch it by the context and even easier if you already know what they are talking about.

So I started to use Youtube and most recently Netflix.

Obs: some shows are better than others. Example: The Simpsons is not a good one for starting because I feel the actor actually speaks too fast.

Today I'm trying MMO games after one catch of shows and movies - I started to use Skype/Raidcall/Teamspeak to engage conversation with the "average Joe".

*This text was auto corrected by a free online grammar check tool*

Comment: Is there a word *bear* that sounds like *beer?* Perhaps a better example is *dear* and *deer*.

Comment: This is a nice account from someone who learnt *English* from use, but it puzzles me how exactly it relates with learning *Portuguese*? The two languages are fundamentally different (modern English is way simpler), as so are available resources.

Comment: English is spelt with a **capital E**.

Answer (score -2):

Learn portuguese isn't a easy work. The accent, pronunciation e the meaning of some words are very different, but, ath the general point, they are the same thing. The portuguese form from Africa(Cabo Verde) is more similar as Portugal.There're goods apps that teach portuguese very weel, as BUSUU and Babel.

Comment: Isto não chega a indicar recursos nenhuns.

Comment: This answer is sub-standard.